# asp.net and google maps inside a tab panel

Tags: asp.net, maps, tabpanel

I have troubles with a map inside a tab panel.
This is what I show:
http://www.pixelfarm.it/gmaps.png
If I resize the browser window all goes ok.
How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger resize function whenever user click on map's tab...
Here is a basic code...it might help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#maptab').bind('onClick', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  });
});
```

Comment: i use the trigger in initialize and don't works, the map is 600x300px

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a function JavaScript:

```
function resize() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

and then the TabContainer you add the property:

```
OnClientActiveTabChanged="resize
     <asp:TabContainer ID="tcEntidades" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"   OnClientActiveTabChanged="resize">
```